# appending in list if sum of elements makes given number

Tags: python, list

I tried to do my homework, where instruction said I need to give a number and the program needs to give me a list of elements which sum into the given number but those elements need to be x**2
For example: if i put in 22, program must give me [2, 4, 16], because elements in list are sum of my input,
thank you

Code:

```
def number(n): 
    ys = []
    for xs in range(1, n + 1): 
        if 2 ** xs <= n: 
            ys.append(2 ** xs) 
            xs += 1 
        else: 
        xs += 1 
    return ys 
print(number(22))
```

Comment: Hi @Nik, welcome to stackoverflow, if you tried could you post your code?

Comment: It would be better if you put it in the post, not in a comment

Comment: the problem is that i cant get rid of an 8, i just need elements that sum an input and not squares that are smaller than the 22

Comment: @DanielMesejo i edited my code into the post

Answer (score 1):

This should probably work.

```
def number(n):
    ys = []
    for xs in range(n,0,-1):
        if 2**xs <= n:
            ys.append(2**xs)
            n -= 2**xs
        xs -= 1
    return ys[::-1]
```

You kept on checking for the same n, but each time you append a new element in your ys, you should subtract it from the number n.
Also, working from high to low might make things easier.

And lastly, the invert slice at the end is just so it returns in the order you asked. You can leave that out and it would return [16, 4, 2].

Comment: Nice answer. Consider fixing your indentation though, because it matters in Python.